# Raspberry Pi 2 and Retropie from Mame cabinet to Pi

Tags: retropie

I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi 2 and have the latest (at writing this thread) version of Retropie running.  My goal was to 3d print a handheld device to run retro games for my son.  Backing up a bit here..I built a full arcade cabinet a few years back running MAME.  Can you see where this is going..?  So all my ROMS are in .zip format.  I ran thru the steps located here (https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/Managing-ROMs) which I though would convert them to the proper .extension...not the case.  Did a test by extracting on my USB jump driver one of my *.zip files into the needed "retropie" root directory, inserted into Raspberry Pi 2 and based off this Youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYMoxvbkYD4), thought once inserted would automatically transfer over and then be listed in the Emulator list under ports...as it was a NES game.  No such luck, not listed.

And also kind of on that topic of non DC/MAC/Apple...and such, if I bring in a NES or Genesis game, I would assume there is a means to create a NES and Genesis emulator from the list.

In the video it was stated that USB is enabled by default.  From within Retropie, how can I get to the terminal screen to get to the config screen to confirm this?

P.S Sorry, not a NIX user but willing to read any links provided to get me where I need to be.  There seems to be so much information, rather not have to sift thru it and only read what is required for the task at hand...so not to be over whelmed.

Comment: Edit:  So apparently I over looked the aspect to copy back my ROMS into proper DIR after PI2 created the needed structure on my USB jump drive.  So I copied over all my .ZIP files into mame4all DIR and rebooted PI2...still no luck.  Just found a thread that the cfg files wont see .zip files.  So I will try to unzip 1 ROM and add to mame4all DIR.  I can only assume that this would be the proper DIR to dump my ROMS into...?

Comment: @steve Robillard, I see you edited my post about "much thanks for any assistance" comment..?  Is this not a helping msg.brd...or am i missing something here?

Comment: The way to show appreciation is by accepting and upvotong posts that are helpful. Just like you will see some users post their name or handle at the end of posts, but the name is included automatically so it is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I am answering as it either needs an answer or needs to be deleted.

> thought once inserted would automatically transfer over and then be listed in the Emulator list under ports

As far as I know this happens automatically. You copy ROMs into the folder appropriate to the emulator. In my case this was under "arcade" for some MAME 0.78 ROMS for old coin-op arcade games. Then when RetroPie is restarted, it detects these ROMs and if they are suitable, it adds the game to the menu system under the appropriate emulator.

> From within Retropie, how can I get to the terminal screen

You call up the menu (there's a list of keys and functions on bottom left in current RetroPie)

[image: menu]

and choose "quit"

[image: menu]

you are dropped out of the graphical front end into a Linux command prompt.

You can later probably restart emulationstation or you can enter command `shutdown -r now` to reboot RetroPie.